# str_replace / addslashes() / htmlspecialchars() .... for quote and double quote

Tags: php

I have a problem.

If I complete my form with " or ' in my form the program bug

I want replace " and ' by code like ' " ' " or addslash or whatever...

Help me please

My code :

```
if (isset($_POST['key'])){
        mysql_select_db($database_dbprotect, $dbprotect);
        $key = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['key']);
       $verif_query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM $bloc_news_entreprise WHERE $bloc_news_entreprise.key='$key'");
        $verif = mysql_query($verif_query, $dbprotect) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_verif = mysql_fetch_assoc($verif);
        $utilisateur = mysql_num_rows($verif);
    if ($utilisateur) {
         echo '<span>Cette key existe déjà</span>';}
    else {
            $key = $_POST['key'];
            $tpl = $_POST['tpl'];
            $urlA = $_POST['urlA'];
            $urlB = $_POST['urlB'];
            $urlC = $_POST['urlC'];
            $urlD = $_POST['urlD'];
            $descriptif = $_POST['descriptif'];
            $bigTitre = $_POST['bigTitre'];
            $titreA = $_POST['titreA'];
            $titreB = $_POST['titreB'];
            $titreC = $_POST['titreC'];
            $titreD = $_POST['titreD'];
                $add_bloc = sprintf("INSERT INTO $bloc_news_entreprise ($bloc_news_entreprise.key, tpl, urlA, urlB, urlC, urlD, descriptif, bigTitre, titreA, titreB, titreC, titreD) VALUES ('$key', '$tpl', '$urlA','$urlB','$urlC','$urlD', '$descriptif', '$bigTitre', '$titreA', '$titreB', '$titreC', '$titreD')");
                mysql_select_db($database_dbprotect, $dbprotect);
                $result = mysql_query($add_bloc, $dbprotect) or die ("Impossible d'ajouter les données utilisateur dans la base de donn&eacute;e");
                header("Location:config-bloc.php?addbloc=ok"); 
                exit;
                }
        }
```

Comment: most DB API's take care of this, stop using a dated soon to be removed one and switch to PDO

Comment: I know but I 'm not a professional and this dated code is ok for me, I just want replace quote and double quote, please help me

Comment: it wont be "ok" if the server is ever upgraded (which it should be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to `htmlentities` before passing to database insert query as follows:

```
htmlentities($_POST['key'], ENT_QUOTES);         // ENT_QUOTES will convert single and double inverted commas to &#039 etc.
```

When you will execute select query, convert data fetched back to single/double inverted commas by using following:

```
html_entity_decode($varReturnedBySelectQuery);  // $varReturnedBySelectQuery is for example returned by select query
```

Comment: like that ? (...)  $titreC = $_POST['titreC'];
            $titreD = $_POST['titreD'];

htmlentities($_POST['key'], ENT_QUOTES);   

                $add_bloc = sprintf("INSERT INTO $bloc_news_entreprise ($bloc_news_entreprise.key, tpl, urlA, urlB, urlC, urlD, descriptif, bigTitre, titreA, titreB, titreC, titreD) VALUES ('$key', '$tpl', '$urlA','$urlB','$urlC','$urlD', '$descriptif', '$bigTitre', '$titreA', '$titreB', '$titreC', '$titreD')");
                mysql_select_db($database_dbprotect, $dbprotect); (...)

Comment: Yes, you can write `$key = htmlentities($_POST['key'], ENT_QUOTES); ` and pass $key variable in insert query

Comment: it's don't work or  I don't understand how use this  :'(
maybe it's more easy for me to use str_replace ?  but i don't to use this and where   str_replace("'", "&quot;",$bigTitre ); .... please help me ... i'm not a pro i'm learner by my self and it's very difficult for me

Comment: Just assign all variables as you did like: `$titreC = $_POST['titreC']; $titreD = $_POST['titreD'];  $key = htmlentities($_POST['key'], ENT_QUOTES);` and then run insert query as you mentioned `"INSERT INTO $bloc_news_entreprise (key, tpl, urlA, urlB, urlC, urlD, descriptif, bigTitre, titreA, titreB, titreC, titreD) VALUES ('$key', '$tpl', '$urlA','$urlB','$urlC','$urlD', '$descriptif', '$bigTitre', '$titreA', '$titreB', '$titreC', '$titreD')"`

Answer (score 0):

First of all mysql function are deprecated you should use pdo_mysql.
Then for quote you can use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or htmlentities 
or [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.addcslashes.php) but don't forget to use the reverse function when you read it.

Comment: Kevin you are french ? can we speak in french please ?

Comment: Yes You can what's your question?